# css-grid creates an imaginary column

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I am creating a simple form, where I want to have this kind of layout

[image: screenshot1]

So far so good, very simple 2 columns with a nested 2 columns, all of them defined with 0.5fr which should be the half of "free-space" if I understood correctly.

But, if I try to reduce the screen, this happens. even if I have NO media queries.

[image: screenshot2]

if you debug with chrome devtools you can see it's creating a 3rd column from nowhere without any element. Any idea?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zzm4gy?file=index.html

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}


.form{
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.two-field{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 0.75fr;
}

/********************/
/* Four elements row*/
/********************/
.four-field{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
}

.four-field .left{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
}

.four-field .right{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 0.75fr;
}
/********************/
/********************/
/********************/

/********************/
/******Buttons*******/
/********************/
.buttons{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 0.75fr;
}

.button-column{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
/********************/
/********************/
/********************/
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <form class="form">
  <div class="two-field">
   <label>First name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
    </div>

    <div class="four-field">
      <div class="left">
        <label>Postal code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Postal code">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <label>Place:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Place" >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="two-field">
      <label>Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone">
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <div class="button-column">
        <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
        <button>Abort</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Fr doesn't mean free space, it means "fractional unit". Add all your fractional units together, and that's the number of total fractional units you'll have for that dimension. So, `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr 8fr` means the grid has 13 fractional units, and 1fr = 1/13 of the grid width.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this explained me several things :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *minimum* size of a *grid item* is as much as its content; which means that `min-width` and `min-height` resolves to `auto`.

> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for grid items, this
>   specification defines that the auto value of min-width/min-height also
>   applies an automatic minimum size in the specified axis to grid items
>   whose overflow is visible and which span at least one track whose min
>   track sizing function is auto.
>
> [MDN](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#min-size-auto)

And note that *input* elements have an *instrinsic width*. So here you can add `min-width: 0` to `input` elements to  *fix* the issue - see demo below:

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}


.form{
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

input {
  min-width: 0; /* ADDED */
}

.two-field{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 0.75fr;
}

/********************/
/* Four elements row*/
/********************/
.four-field{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
}

.four-field .left{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
}

.four-field .right{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 0.75fr;
}
/********************/
/********************/
/********************/

/********************/
/******Buttons*******/
/********************/
.buttons{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 0.75fr;
}

.button-column{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
/********************/
/********************/
/********************/
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <form class="form">
  <div class="two-field">
   <label>First name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
    </div>

    <div class="four-field">
      <div class="left">
        <label>Postal code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Postal code">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <label>Place:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Place" >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="two-field">
      <label>Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone">
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <div class="button-column">
        <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
        <button>Abort</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

**Suggestion**

But there is no need for a lot of *nesting* here (I am suggesting a change in markup here) - you can make this work in a simple 4-column grid layout like below:

```css
.form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  min-width: 0;
}

input[name=firstname],
input[name=phone] {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.button-column {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <form class="form">
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <label>Postal code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Postal code">
    <label>Place:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Place">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone">
    <div class="button-column">
      <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
      <button>Abort</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your snippet, I'll try to use this layout and see if will fit my needs. In the meantime, you didn't answer the question, why there's the hidden column? :(

Comment: @LucaTrazzi sorry for the late reply, have added the explanations, check it out...