# How can I prevent a 100vh image from expanding the viewpoint?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

For my `#l-splash` image, I'm having issues with the `height: 100vh` expanding past the viewpoint.

I have tried changing the overflow and different max-heights. I want my width to take up 100% of the left grid so it exactly takes up half of the screen. I suspect the problem is how my nav bar is *stickied* but I ideally need it to continue sticking to the top of the screen. Thanks for the help

https://jsfiddle.net/mtgcosxd/1/

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #fffaf0;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /*font-family: 'Gotham-Light', gotham;*/
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fffaf0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
  color: #80985d;
}

.navLink {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content] 1fr [images] 1fr
}

.content {
  grid-column: content;
  background: #2f6e84;
}

#l-splash {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <header>
    <div class="navLink" id="story-scroll">Our Story</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="menu-scroll">Menu</div>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" id="logo" lt="logo">
    <div class="navLink" id="press-scroll">Press</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="contact-scroll">Contact</div>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="content">
    <div id="splash container">
      <img id="l-splash" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526069631228-723c945bea6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80">
    </div>
```

Comment: Check the height of your Navbar and subtract that height from the view-height
height: calc(100vh - height-of-navbar)

Comment: Well 100vh = 100% of viewPORT height. so 100% + something ( the navbar height ) is > 100% . So of course it overflows the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set `height: 100vh` on the image - as you are already having *flexboxes* and *grids* in your layout, you can *inherit* the heights using a *column flexbox* wrapper on `body`- here are the changes:

- made you `body` a *column flexbox* and gave 100vh height,
- allow the `container` to fill the remaining space left by the `nav` using `flex: 1` on the `container`,
- add `height: 100%` to the *container* of the `img`,
- fill the image in its container using `height: 100%` and using [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit),

```css
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fffaf0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  /* made a flexbox */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /* full-height */
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #fffaf0;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /*font-family: 'Gotham-Light', gotham;*/
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
  color: #80985d;
}

.navLink {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content] 1fr [images] 1fr;
  flex: 1; /* added */
}

.content {
  grid-column: content;
  background: #2f6e84;
}

.content > div {
  height: 100%; /* added */
}

#l-splash {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* added */
  overflow: auto;
  display: block; /* remove inline element whitespace */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <header>
    <div class="navLink" id="story-scroll">Our Story</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="menu-scroll">Menu</div>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" id="logo" lt="logo">
    <div class="navLink" id="press-scroll">Press</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="contact-scroll">Contact</div>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="splash container">
      <img id="l-splash" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526069631228-723c945bea6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80">
    </div>
```

---

#### But you still have overflow - *what now?*

- Add `min-height: 0` to `container` so that you *override* the default `min-height: auto` for *flex items* in column direction,

  You can see some examples of why you need to do this below:

  - [Flexbox affects overflow-wrap behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277368/flexbox-affects-overflow-wrap-behavior/52278099#52278099)
  - [Flexbox resize and scrollable overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303538/flexbox-resize-and-scrollable-overflow/55303600#55303600)
  - [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)
- Similarly `min-height: auto` for a *grid item* can be overridden using `min-height: 0` on the `content` element

  You can see some examples of why you need to do this below:

  - [css-grid creates an imaginary column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007253/css-grid-creates-an-imaginary-column/55007797#55007797)
  - [How to make images stay within the rows of a css grid container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303488/how-to-make-images-stay-within-the-rows-of-a-css-grid-container/46305403#46305403)

See demo below:

```css
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fffaf0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  /* made a flexbox */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /* full-height */
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #fffaf0;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /*font-family: 'Gotham-Light', gotham;*/
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
  color: #80985d;
}

.navLink {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content] 1fr [images] 1fr;
  flex: 1; /* added */
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}

.content {
  grid-column: content;
  background: #2f6e84;
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}

.content > div {
  height: 100%; /* added */
}

#l-splash {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* added */
  overflow: auto;
  display: block; /* remove inline element whitespace */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <header>
    <div class="navLink" id="story-scroll">Our Story</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="menu-scroll">Menu</div>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" id="logo" lt="logo">
    <div class="navLink" id="press-scroll">Press</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="contact-scroll">Contact</div>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="splash container">
      <img id="l-splash" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526069631228-723c945bea6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the height of the nav/header from the height of the `#l-splash` div. E.g.

```
header { 
  ...
  height: 50px; 
  max-height: 50px; 
}

#l-splash {
  ...
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

If your nav or other divs have margins, you may need to include those in your height calculation. E.g.

```
header { 
  ...
  height: 50px; 
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#l-splash {
  ...
  height: calc(100vh - 55px);
}
```

Comment: This solution sounds simple enough but why does the logo shrink when I assign a height for the header?