# PrismJs not overflowing with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid, prismjs

I have a page layout with a elastic content div and a fixed width column on the right. For that, I have the following basic structure:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="content">
    Content here
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Fixed right column
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: auto 280px;
    width: 500px;
}

.content {
  background: tomato;
}

.column {
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

I expected the `auto` content to fill up the total space minus the fixed column width. That happens indeed, except when the content of the div, being a prism tag, overflows that width.
Instead of generating an horizontal scroll bar on the PrismJs div, it simply overflows the content div and pushes the column further right.

**Any ideas on how to make a scrollbar appear on the div instead of pushing the column?**

Note that if I put a fixed value for the content width it works as expected.

Here's an example:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: auto 280px;
    width: 500px;
}

.content {
  background: tomato;
}

.column {
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/prism/1.2.0/themes/prism.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/prism/1.2.0/themes/prism-coy.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/prism/1.2.0/prism.js"></script>


<div class="grid">
  <div class="content">
    <pre><code class="language-javascript">@Component({
        selector: "main",
        directives: [],
        template: `
            &lt;button
                (tap) = "onTapMe()"
                text = "tap me" /&gt;
        `
    })
    class MainPage {
        onTapMe() {
            alert("Hello from Angular 2");
        }
        // long coment pushing the right column further right !!!
    }
    </code></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working fiddle to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/4crm25pq/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default *grid items* have `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto` (just like *flex items*). So you can set `min-width: 0` and add `oveflow: auto` to *fix* this - see demo below:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: auto 280px;
    width: 500px;
}

.content {
  background: tomato;
  min-width: 0; /* added */
  overflow: auto; /* added */
}

.column {
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/prism/1.2.0/themes/prism.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/prism/1.2.0/themes/prism-coy.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/prism/1.2.0/prism.js"></script>


<div class="grid">
  <div class="content">
    <pre><code class="language-javascript">@Component({
        selector: "main",
        directives: [],
        template: `
            &lt;button
                (tap) = "onTapMe()"
                text = "tap me" /&gt;
        `
    })
    class MainPage {
        onTapMe() {
            alert("Hello from Angular 2");
        }
        // long coment pushing the right column further right !!!
    }
    </code></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see some examples of of this behaviour below:

- [css-grid creates an imaginary column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007253/css-grid-creates-an-imaginary-column/55007797#55007797)
- [How to make images stay within the rows of a css grid container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303488/how-to-make-images-stay-within-the-rows-of-a-css-grid-container/46305403#46305403)